# how to create Sliding Up Panel without using any library in android

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, layoutparams

In single view I want to display map and list of places in `recyclerview` so I divided my layout by using weight. Now it will show map half screen and list half screen based on place `recyclerview` scrolling I want to display location of the place in google map. At same time while scrolling I want to make my list 80% bigger after that when they using map it should become normal size this all working. Now what I want is an animation for increasing height like google music.

Code for collapse:

```
Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            if (interpolatedTime == 1) {
                v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().height = (int) (initialHeight * interpolatedTime);
                v.requestLayout();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int) (initialHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
```

Code for expand:

```
v.measure(AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    final int targetHeight = (height / 100) * 40;

    // Older versions of android (pre API 21) cancel animations for views with a height of 0.
    v.getLayoutParams().height = 1;
    v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Animation a = new Animation() {
        @Override
        protected void applyTransformation(float interpolatedTime, Transformation t) {
            v.getLayoutParams().height = interpolatedTime == 1
                    ? AbsoluteLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
                    : (int) (targetHeight * interpolatedTime);
            v.requestLayout();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean willChangeBounds() {
            return true;
        }
    };
    // 1dp/ms
    a.setDuration((int) (targetHeight / v.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density));
    v.startAnimation(a);
```

Animation smooth is not coming can some one help me

Comment: Are you still looking for a solution?

Comment: could be great to give us the solution ;)